# Why is time passed being incorrect calculated across processes?

Tags: c, time, signals, extern

I am writing a program that sends a signal in one process and receives it in a thread in another. I have the entire program written with signals being caught and handled, as well as any synchronization issues. The problem is, I am trying to log the time the signal was sent and the time the signal was received. Though the values across the process vary strangely.

Here is how I did it.

I have a header file `header.h` which includes a shared global `extern struct timespec begin, end;`. The reason I made these shared was that I would need the beginning time to calculate the time elapsed since the program began.

Here is how I calculate the time elapsed.

I am using the POSIX clock_gettime().
I start the program and begin the timer, then when a signal is sent I run:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
long seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
long nanoseconds = end.tv_nsec - begin.tv_nsec;
double elapsed = seconds + nanoseconds * 1e-9;
```

This all occurs in the main program.
The second process is another program which is `exec()` in a child process and that is where the signal catch occurs.
When I catch the signal, I store some data about it in a struct and store it in a buffer for another thread to read and log from.

```
typedef struct
{
    int sig;
    double time;
    long int tid;
} data;
```

Here's what I do in one of the threads:

```
data d;
d.sig = 2;
d.tid = pthread_self();
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
long seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;
long nanoseconds = end.tv_nsec - begin.tv_nsec;
double elapsed = seconds + nanoseconds * 1e-9;
d.time = elapsed;
put(d);
```

The problem is my outputs are vastly different. In my `sentlog.txt` the time is represented correctly, with enough precision to see a difference.

```
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.000286 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.082671 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.155440 seconds
SIGUSR1 sent at 1.250770 seconds
SIGUSR1 sent at 1.314637 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.398995 seconds
SIGUSR1 sent at 1.460559 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.498223 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.577555 seconds
SIGUSR1 sent at 1.618036 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.684488 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.743165 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.780100 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.871603 seconds
SIGUSR1 sent at 1.901293 seconds
SIGUSR2 sent at 1.944139 seconds
SIGUSR1 sent at 1.984142 seconds
SIGUSR1 sent at 2.040130 seconds
```

While the `receivelog.txt` is not.

Here is how I log to the file and stdout

```
if (d.sig == 1)
        {
            printf("SIGUSR1 received by thread %ld at time %f\n", d.tid, d.time);
            fflush(stdout);
            fprintf(fpRecieve, "Thread %ld received SIGUSR1 at %f seconds\n", d.tid, d.time);
            fflush(fpRecieve);
        }
        else if (d.sig == 2)
        {
            printf("SIGUSR2 received by thread %ld at time %f\n", d.tid, d.time);
            fflush(stdout);
            fprintf(fpRecieve, "Thread %ld received SIGUSR2 at %f seconds\n", d.tid, d.time);
            fflush(fpRecieve);
        }
```

```
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008328.531628 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008328.613999 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008328.686767 seconds
Thread 139995372357376 received SIGUSR1 at 1670008328.782099 seconds
Thread 139995372357376 received SIGUSR1 at 1670008328.845975 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008328.930328 seconds
Thread 139995372357376 received SIGUSR1 at 1670008328.991889 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008329.029554 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008329.108883 seconds
Thread 139995372357376 received SIGUSR1 at 1670008329.149364 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008329.215814 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008329.274493 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008329.311425 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008329.402932 seconds
Thread 139995372357376 received SIGUSR1 at 1670008329.432621 seconds
Thread 139995363964672 received SIGUSR2 at 1670008329.475466 seconds
```

Why can I not simply just use the same operation as before?

Comment: @CraigEstey: The post says the signal handler (“When I catch the signal”) stores data in a buffer for another thread to read and log.

Comment: Likely not the issue, yet `long seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;` should be `time_t seconds = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec;`

Answer (score 1):

> I have a header file header.h which includes a shared global `extern struct timespec begin, end;`. The reason I made these shared was that I would need the beginning time to calculate the time elapsed since the program began.

The `end` does *not* need to be global (and *should* not be). Only `begin` needs to be global.

When `end` is global, multiple threads can access it at the same time. This is a race condition and is UB (undefined behavior).

Make `end` a function scoped variable.

---

You're *not* showing the code for `put` or the [ring?] queue definition.

Access to it should be with a mutex or `stdatomic.h` primitives.

Although a bit trickier to implement, I usually prefer the atomic functions.

---

Also, I agree that the code should be using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.

Comment: I assured mutual exclusion, I excluded it mainly because it doesn't have much use to the question

Comment: @Bryan Because you posted so little [too little] code, we have to guess. Since you made the global definition error, you could just as easily have made a mutex related error as well. I presume your code is small enough that you could post it entirely as a single code block. Trying to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by just cutting down to just show disconnected fragments doesn't work too well.